# How can i get data from clicked button in Slack

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, slack

[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ZUe.png)

I have those two buttons in Slack, every user getting message with this button, I need to do action on my own webpage when button is clicked, how can i get data from those buttons when there are clciked.

Comment: what data you want to gather from slack ? or just redirect to your website ?

Comment: Just payload. Maybe only slackId of the user who clicked the button

Answer (score -1):

So, if you want to get payload from SlackApi, on your localhost, try ngrok, cuz SlackApi cant send payload from any action to your localhost, then just create a cotroller or method to get payload and interact with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).